# Will paralyzing a grappler break the grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, conditions, grapple

Assume you're grappled but you have a melee attack that can cause the [paralyzed condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed). If you successfully paralyze your grappler, will that break the grapple? Paralysis causes someone to be [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) which prevents them from taking actions or reactions, but resisting an attempt to break the grapple (in a contested roll) doesn't require either of these from the grappler.

Is the answer different if the grappler is using the [Coiling Grasp Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2401178-coiling-grasp-tattoo)? In this case, the grappled creature can try to escape using an appropriate check, but it's not a contested roll, so the tattoo's ability to maintain a grapple seems unaffected by its host's paralysis.

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote, the downvote tooltip mentions lack of research, and I think reading whole the grappled condition is the bare minimum you could have done, and it would have answered this for you.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I thought I had followed the various logic chains, but I guess the "incapacitated" nested inside the paralyzed condition got me turned around and I wasn't thinking clearly enough to catch it -- especially since I was confused by the mechanical difference in the tattoo's grapple. I would gladly delete my question, but the system won't let me since you've answered it.

Answer (score 17):

#### “The condition ends if the grappler is incapacitated”

The grappled condition states:

> - The condition ends if the grappler is incapacitated

So yes, paralyzing the grappler ends the grapple since paralyzed includes incapacitated.

Comment: What about the Coiling Grasp Tattoo?

Comment: @enkryptor Same answer for the same reason, but I’ll add a note about it.